# How do I run an abstract method from Class object extending abstract class in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to call an abstract method via a Class object.

So I have my abstract class as following:

```
public abstract class Module implements SimpleModule{

    public abstract void run();

}
```

Now I have a class implementing this abstract class.

I've used Reflection to get all classes implementing my abstract class 'Module'. I have stored all the results as following:

```
private Set<Class<? extends Module>> modules = new HashSet<>();
```

Now what I would like to know is how to run the abstract method 'run()' defined in the abstract class 'Module' via this map. I've made a loop, looping through all these classes as following:

```
for(Class<? extends Module> clazz : modules){
    //Here I want the 'run' method to be called.
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? I would appreciate it a lot. Thanks

Comment: You need an instance to call `run()`...

Comment: `clazz.newInstance().run()`?

Comment: In order to run an instance method, you need an instance. You seem only to have classes. If you haven't instantiated the classes, that is the step you are missing.

Comment: `((Module)clazz.newInstance()).run();`

Comment: "I've used Reflection to get all classes implementing my abstract class 'Module'."  You may have obtained *some* such classes reflectively, but you cannot be confident that you obtained them all.

Comment: You might want to check if clazz is also abstract before trying to call run. Then there is the issue about the constructor, hopefully there is a zero-arg constructor.

Comment: You cannot ever run an abstract method.  By definition, an abstract method has no implementation.  You can run a *concrete* method that overrides an abstract one, however.  Generally, you do not need to pay attention to the fact that you are doing so.

Comment: @brso05 - `Module` is abstract, so can you make a new instance of it with a cast?

Comment: @cricket_007 you're not making a new instance of it...you are casting it.

Comment: @cricket_007 you need to cast it because `.newInstance()` returns an `Object` which does not have a method `run()`...

Comment: @brso05 - I got that part, just not the casting to an abstract class, then calling an abstract method on it.

Comment: @cricket_007 you're not calling the abstract method from the `superclass`. You are calling the concrete method implemented in the `subclass`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be doing this instead.

1. Define some *concrete* implementation of your abstract `Module` class, so you can actually call `run()` with some defined behavior.
2. Store the Objects themselves instead of the class because while all classes may be instances of a `Module`, you would need to cast them later to get the defined `run()` behavior for the specific class.

---

Example concrete implementation

```
class MyModule extends Module {
     public void run() {
         // TODO: Implement this
     }
}
```

---

Then, in the rest of your code, you can define the collection with simply the interface to say that this Set contains anything that implements `SimpleModule`, which I assume is where the `run()` method is originally from.

```
Set<SimpleModule> modules = new HashSet<>();
modules.add(new MyModule());  

for(SimpleModule m : modules){
    m.run();
}
```